# remove all fully qualified names from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database, lets say AP, some of its objects use fully qualified names like,

select * from AP.dbo.Customer

I restored this database to another machine and renamed the database to APDev, but now all the fully qualified name object references don't work, is there a simple way to remove all the qualified name.

Thanks

Comment: remove it from what?

Comment: From `some of its objects`.  I guess that means things like stored procedures, functions, perhaps view definitions.  @abeperl, please be more specific.

Comment: I guess he still wants to use the queries from the other database (other machine) but they don't work on the restored database as it's named APDev instead of just AP.

Answer (score 1):

After you restore the database to New Database say APDev, Generate the SQL Script for all DB object for this new APDev database, then  Replace AP to APDev or Remove it, then execute again this Updated/Modified SQL script on new database. Then All object will be restored with new name.

To Generate the SQL Script from New APDev Database,

```
In Object Explorer, expand Databases, right-click a database, point to Tasks, 
and then click Generate Scripts. Follow the steps in the wizard 
to script the database objects.
```

To See how to Generate Script, Follow http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx